# Tapestry 4 Dynamic image asset

Tags: java, tapestry

I have images stored in a database I need to serve within a tapestry page.

I was about to write a servlet (simple enough) to serve the image like I always have but I figured using an asset or a service was more tapestry oriented.

What would be the simplest/tidiest way to include a dynamic image within a tapestry page?

Bare in mind I am pulling a byte array out of the database based on a unique identifier set by the page and that I need to set the content type on the response header.

Advice appreciated, p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve dynamic content, you can implement an [`IEngineService`](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry/engine/IEngineService.html), configure it as a service, and then point your download links towards that service.

[This page](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/SendingDiferentContentTypes) on the Tapestry wiki should help you get started.

Comment: thanks henning, implemented something very similar this morning.